# rails 3 loop through hash but not repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop through a hash of times with a nested Booking class. I want it to make a table of times from the hash and say "Available" or "Booked" if there is a booking object with the same hour Time as the value of the hash.

index.html.erb

```
table
<%  @times.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| %>
tr
<td><%= key %></td>

  <% for booking in @bookings %>
    <% if booking.time.strftime("%H").to_s == value.to_s then %>
     <td> <em> Booked </em> </td>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>

  <% if booking.time.strftime("%H").to_s != value.to_s then %>
  <td> <em> Available </em> </td>
  <% end %> 
/tr
<% end %>
/table
```

This produces this:

```
9am     Available
10am    Available
11am    Available 
12am    Available
1pm     Booked  Available
2pm     Available
3pm     Available
4pm     Booked
5pm     Available
6pm     Available
7pm     Available
8pm     Available
9pm     Available
```

So it is repeating the loop on 1pm because that value has change the second time round. How can I avoid this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chowletts answer seems to do what you want, but I can't stand the idea of doing unnecessary calculations inside the loop when it is not necessary. So here's my solution:

```
<%  
    booking_times = @bookings.map{ |booking| booking.time.hour }
    @times.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| 
%>
  tr
    <td><%= key %></td>
    <td><em><%= booking_times.include?(value.to_i) ? "Booked" : "Available" %></em></td>
  /tr
<% end %>
```

Comment: for more fastest search you can use hash: `booking_hash = @bookings.each_with_object({}) {|i, a| a[i.time.hour] = i }` usage: `booking_hash[value.to_i]?`

Comment: Cool!, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you effectively display "Available" if the *last* booking doesn't match this time. You could use a flag, which you set if you find a booking:

```
<table>
<%  @times.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| %>
<tr>
<td><%= key %></td>
  <% booked = false %>
  <% for booking in @bookings %>
    <% if booking.time.strftime("%H").to_s == value.to_s then %>
     <td> <em> Booked </em> </td>
     <% booked = true %>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>

  <% if !booked %>
  <td> <em> Available </em> </td>
  <% end %> 
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you set up a `has_one` (or whatever) relationship between `Time` and `Booking`, you could just check if the time has a booking associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

More simple way:

```
table
<%  @times.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| %>
tr
<td><%= key %></td>

  <% if @bookings.index{|booking| booking.time.strftime("%H").to_s == value.to_s}  then %>
    <td> <em> Booked </em> </td>
  <% else %>
    <td> <em> Available </em> </td>
  <% end %> 

/tr
<% end %>
/table
```